# How to display a user selected value in combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView that will store an employee ID, employee last name, and employee first name to a string on a cell click

```
rEmpID = this.dtDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["REVIEWER"].Value.ToString(); 
rEmpFirst = this.dtDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["EMP_FIRSTNAME1"].Value.ToString();
rEmpLast = this.dtDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["EMP_LASTNAME1"].Value.ToString();
```

This works fine and will store the proper values. After this a new form is created that contains a combobox that is public. This combobox is databound to a table in sql server that contains employee id, employee last name, and employee first name. The display member of the combobox is the employee last name and the value member is the employee id. I want to be able to take the rEmpID and have it change the selected value in the combobox. I have tried

```
pForm.assComboBox.SelectedItem = pForm.revComboBox.Items.IndexOf(rEmpID);
pForm.revComboBox.SelectedIndex = pForm.revComboBox.FindStringExact(rEmpLast);
```

Comment: SelectedValue = rEmpId

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Hmm it works for me in a sample code that I crafted quickly.

Comment: `pForm.revComboBox.SelectedIndex = pForm.revComboBox.Items.IndexOf(rEmpID);` ?

Comment: Yea from what I've read it should work but when I try it in my code it just doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Probably it does, but then you somehow change it somewhere?

Comment: I've also tried your suggestion Magnetron but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys I have come up with a solution. It's not good, but it works. On the form with the combobox I added a public label. I then set the text of the label to be the rEmpID value. On Form_Load I set

```
revComboBox.SelectedValue = label.Text;
```

Again not great, but for anyone in the future who somehow comes upon this problem and needs a quick and dirty fix this will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't write this as a comment, so here is sample I have used:

```
void Main()
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext(@"server=.\SQLexpress;trusted_connection=yes;database=Northwind");

    Table<Category> Categories = db.GetTable<Category>();
    Table<Product> Products = db.GetTable<Product>();

    Form f = new Form { Text="ComboBox ornek", Height=200, Width=500 };
    ComboBox cb1 = new ComboBox{ Left=10, Top=10, Width=450, Font=new Font("Courier New",8) };
    ComboBox cb2 = new ComboBox{ Left=10, Top=60, Width=450, Font=new Font("Courier New",8) };

    f.Controls.AddRange( new Control[] {cb1, cb2} );

    cb1.DataSource = Categories.OrderByDescending(c => c.CategoryName).ToList();
    cb1.ValueMember = "CategoryId";
    cb1.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
    //cb1.SelectedIndex = -1;


    cb1.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) => { 

    var selectedCategory = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem as Category;
    cb2.DataSource = null;
    cb2.Items.Clear();
    if (selectedCategory != null)
    {
      cb2.DataSource = Products.Where (p => p.CategoryId == selectedCategory.CategoryId).ToList();
      cb2.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
      cb2.ValueMember = "ProductId";
    }
    };

    cb1.SelectedValue = 5;
    f.ShowDialog();
}


[Table(Name = "Categories")]
public class Category
{
    [Column]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Table(Name = "Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Column]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I need to change my selected value to an int? Right now rEmpID is a number stored in a string.

Comment: Side note: Try setting the DataSource after the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties to prevent multiple invalidation calls by the control.

Comment: @Person Oh, why would you do that. And the "employee id" is not a string I guess.

Comment: Idk I was just throwing stuff at the wall at this point. This problem has been bugging me.

Comment: Thanks for trying guys, but I need to take a break from this problem and work on something else for a bit.